# chrome plugin add or delete some elements in facebook newsfeed DOM tree via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing chrome-plugin, that can to add some functions in facebook's newsfeed or delete some elements from DOM-tree.
But i have a trouble.
At first the page had been shown, and just only after this DOM-elements was added or deleted. But I want to make the page has already been shown with these elements.
How to do it?

*manifest.json*

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Facebook plugin",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Facebook plugin",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "https://www.facebook.com/*", "webNavigation", "background", "<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

*background.js*

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
        code: 
                ' $("#home_stream li div.attachmentText span.caption:contains(\'youtube.com\')").closest("li").empty();'
    });

});
```

and *jquery.js* - latest jquery library release.
Please,tell me what i do wrongly? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.
1. add to *manifest.json* in "content_scripts" section - css: ["style.css"]:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://www.facebook.com/*"],
        css: ["style.css"],
        "js": ["jquery.js"]
    }
]
```

2. add into *style.css* next code:

```
body {display: none;}
```

3. add to *background.js*

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details) {    

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {
        code: 
            ' $("#home_stream li div.attachmentText span.caption:contains(\'youtube.com\')").closest("li").empty();' +
        ' $("body").css("display", "inline");'
    });
});
```